# Präposition 'wider' mit Dativ

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

Gibt es einen nachvollziehbaren Grund, etwa etymologisch, weswegen die Präposition 'wider' vor einem Akkusativ stehen muss? Der Gebrauch mit dem Dativ scheint sehr weit verbreitet zu sein.

Des Weiteren frage ich mich, ob hier nicht vielleicht eine Doppelverwendung von 'wider' vorliegt, so wie Präpositionen wie 'auf', 'in' etc. eine allative oder lokative Bedeutung haben, je nachdem, ob ein Akkusativ oder Dativ folgt.

Comment: Hättest Du Beispiele für eine korrekte Verwendung des Dativs? Bei der Bedeutung "gegen" fällt es mir schwer etwas anderes als den Akkusativ als korrekt zu erachten.

Comment: Könntest du uns bitte Beispiele nennen?

Comment: Wg. Dativ: Im Gegensatz zu 'wider' steht **'zuwider'** als Präposition hinter einem Dativ: »Seinem Gewissen zuwider nahm er das Geld an.« (Dat.) »Er handelte seinem Gewissen zuwider.« (Dat.) VERSUS »Er handelte wider sein Gewissen.« (Akk.) Falls also jemand fälschlicherweise 'wider' mit Dativ verwendet, könnte das auf einer irrtümlichen Übertragung basieren, zumal 'zuwider' wohl öfter vorkommt als 'wider'.

Comment: Ich höre bisweilen einen (genauso falschen) Genitiv mit *wider*, wie in *wider besseren Wissens*, aber einen Dativ habe ich, glaube ich, noch nie gehört. Ist das möglicherweise eine regionale Erscheinung?

Comment: Auch könnte "trotz" Einfluss gehabt haben. Es stand ursprünglich eher mit Dativ, nicht Genitiv.

Answer (score 12):

Die Präpositionen *wider* und *gegen* werden [mit dem Akkusativ](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/Akkusativ.html) verwendet, weil sie eine Bewegung ausdrücken.

*wider* wird im Deutschen übrigens nur noch selten verwendet, oft in Überschriften zu Pamphleten (*"Wider die Gewalt"*) oder in festen Redewendungen, z. B. *[wider besseres Wissen](https://www.korrekturen.de/beliebte_fehler/wider-besseren-wissens.shtml)*.

Anmerkung: Ich persönlich habe im Gegensatz zur Aussage in der Frage selten einen Dativ mit *wider* gehört oder gelesen.

Comment: Hat nichts mit der Frage zu tun: »wider« ist natürlich Teil vieler noch gebräuchlicher Worte _wider_sprechen, _wider_lich, an_wider_n, _wider_wärtig, _wider_stehen, _wider_sinnig, _wider_rufen, _wider_legen ...

Comment: Wider den Dativ!